# Error on automating data entry

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded a macro & integrated together with some codes I researched and tested, which worked individually. However, having combined them all together, I stumbled across errors running the macro. Pop out a message box which displays

> Compile Error: Expected End With

Would appreciate all the help I could get to solve it

```
Sub Book1UpdateDelete()
    '
    ' Book1UpdateDelete Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+g
    '
    'Select values in a column from specified workbook and sheet
    Dim LR As Long, cell As Range, rng As Range

    Windows("Y738 Data").Activate

    With Sheets("Graph data")
        LR = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In .Range("B4:B" & LR)
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                If rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng = cell
                Else
                    Set rng = Union(rng, cell)
                End If
            End If
        Next cell

        rng.Select
    End With

    Selection.Copy

    'Open next workbook
    Windows("Y783").Activate
    'Open Sheet L
    Sheets("L").Select
    'Select empty field fromn column AA
    Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    'paste selection to empty field
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    'Go back to previous workbook & delete column
    Windows("Y738").Activate

    With Sheets("Graph data")
        Columns("B:B").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        Sheets("Graph Data").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `With Sheets("Graph data")` about 5 lines from the bottom has no corresponding `End With`.  At the moment though, you aren't making use of the `With` (no subsequent code has any methods / properties starting with just a `.`) so you may as well get rid of the `With` (or fix the subsequent code to use it).

Comment: If you format your code nicely and indent it correctly (what I did for you in your question) then you clearly see that issue. The first rule you should **always** follow is "*format your code nicely and use correct indentation*" and use human readable variable naming. Otherwise finding errors can be very cumbersome or even impossible.

Comment: @YowE3K I see. Thanks for explaining (:
Appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed and end with at the bottom of your code.

Try this (untested)

```
Sub Book1UpdateDelete()
'
' Book1UpdateDelete Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+g
'
'Select values in a column from specified workbook and sheet
Dim LR As Long, cell As Range, rng As Range
Windows("Y738 Data").Activate
With Sheets("Graph data")
LR = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In .Range("B4:B" & LR)
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = cell
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next cell
rng.Select

End With
Selection.Copy

'Open next workbook
Windows("Y783").Activate
'Open Sheet L
Sheets("L").Select
'Select empty field fromn column AA
Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
'paste selection to empty field
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
'Go back to previous workbook & delete column
Windows("Y738").Activate
With Sheets("Graph data")
Columns("B:B").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Sheets("Graph Data").Select
End with
End Sub
```

Comment: The `With` statement is completely useless and doesn't affect the code in any way. It can be removed without changing the behavior of that code.

Comment: @Peh Got it, thanks for letting me know & formatting my codes too.
Appreciate it